# sencha touch html in tabBar not showing when I add title bar

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am trying to create a layout that has a title bar and a tab bar just right below it.

I know how to assign a simple html text in each tab and I made it work when I just use tab bar without the title bar. It's as follows:

```
Ext.define('MyThirdApp.view.Feed', {
extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',
xtype: 'feedcard',

config:{
    tabBar: {
        layout: {
            pack: 'center'
        }
    },
    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },

    items: [
        {
            title: 'tab1',
            html: 'this is tab 1'
        },
        {
            title: 'tab2',
            html: 'here is tab2!'
        },
        {
            title: 'tab3',
            html: 'here is tab3!'
        }
        ]
    }
});
```

It works fine. Then I tried to add a title bar on top of it by defining another view and adding this tab bar in it

```
Ext.define('MyThirdApp.view.Main', {
fullscreen: true,
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
requires: [
    'Ext.TitleBar',
    'MyThirdApp.view.Feed'
],

config: {
    items:[
        {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'The main title',
        },
        {xtype: 'feedcard'}
    ]
}


});
```

and it shows the title bar with just the tab bar below it. It doesn't show any html even when I click on all the different tabs. I have no idea why this happens or what I did wrong, and I tried playing with the layout and the extend: property of MyThirdApp.view.Main, changing it to Container or Panel, none works. I tried looking around at the Kitchensink example from Sencha but I found no part of the code that defines the title bar in their Tab bar UI source. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `layout: 'fit'` in your main view:-

```
Ext.define('MyThirdApp.view.Main', {
fullscreen: true,
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
requires: [
    'Ext.TitleBar',
    'MyThirdApp.view.Feed'
],

config: {
    layout: 'fit',
    items:[
        {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'The main title',
        },
        {xtype: 'feedcard'}
    ]
}
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that but the title bar is completely gone. the tabPanel works fine though. any ideas?

Comment: Make the titlebar `docked: 'top'`.

Answer (score 0):

Set `layout: 'fit'` for your Main view.